# Calculator randomly opening - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, display, calculator

I have been dealing with a problem where calculator opens up randomly. When this started happening I ran into multiple issues at the same time such as <kbd>Win</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key not working and random symbols getting typed (`_!?_!?_!?`...).

I fixed this problem by disabling laptop keyboard drivers, but the calculator randomly opening still didn't get fixed so I tried to uninstalling the calculator app. Next time it happened it asked me to open ms-calculator in another app and gave me the option to find another app in Microsoft Store.

I had also tried doing a virus scan (Malwarebytes) and I also tried installing a new Windows 10 and thought that would fix it for sure, but it didn't. I have also checked my task scheduler and startup apps in Task Manager and nothing included calculator.

The issue persists after disabling all keyboard drivers. I have also tried doing a clean boot and still nothing. It is a ASUS Laptop, specifically Rog Strix G531GU and it has a touchpad with number pad built into it and it needs a driver to work, even that is disabled.

This laptop also has different modes that change the gamma and color of the display, after the calculator opens it also changes the mode of that. If there is a fix for getting rid of the pop up to find a new app its good enough for me.

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I also tried installing a new Windows 10 and thought that would fix it for sure, but it didn't.      .........   After reading the entire post, does this not suggest a new keyboard with built in touchpad?

Comment: Hello, instead of apologizing for wall of text, press enter a few times to make your question much more readable next time.

Answer (score 0):

In the MyAsus app, there should be an option to disable the NumLock on the touchpad. That should stop the accidental swiping.